# websphere 9.0.0.6 - configuration transaction mode ECI_EXTENDED or ECI_EXTEND

Tags: configuration, websphere, cics

I am using websphere application server 9.0.0.6.

I have configured a cics Ressource Adapter and the connection factory for that, to connect my cics.

For that connection I am using the cicseci-9.0.0.2.rar driver.

I can connect my CICS but I get an Abend Code:

```
com.ibm.connector2.cics.CICSTxnAbendException: CTG9638E Transaction Abend occurred in CICS. Abend Code=: AZI6, error code: AZI6

    at com.ibm.connector2.cics.ECIManagedConnection.checkReturnCode(ECIManagedConnection.java:1643)

    at com.ibm.connector2.cics.ECIManagedConnection.call(ECIManagedConnection.java:1442)

    at com.ibm.connector2.cics.ECIConnection.call(ECIConnection.java:122)

    at com.ibm.connector2.cics.ECIInteraction.execute(ECIInteraction.java:264)

    at at.grz.jp.cics.Interaction.executeSequence(Interaction.java:179)
```

Due to the reason, that I use transaction mode ECI_EXTENDED instead of ECI_NO_EXTEND.

So I am trying to find a possibility to configure that parameter.  On websphere I can't find a custom property that could be fit.
Is it possible to control this by my application?

Any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 0):

The transactional controls for requests made over the ECI resources adapter are controlled by the TransactionAttribute of the method containing the ECI call.

By default methods are called with a TransactionAttributeType of REQUIRED which means a new transaction will be started if it doesn’t already exist and this causes the ECI request to be sent with ECI_EXTENDED.

If you set the TransactionAttributeType to NEVER then there will be no transaction when the ECI call is made and the request will be sent with ECI_NO_EXTEND.

Comment: Hi @crshnburn thanks for your help. but where can I set the Transaction Attribute Type to NEVER ? is this an websphere application custom property in the websphere console ? where exactly ? Thanks